# how to improve performance for adjacency jqgrid with large data

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid and I have implemented an adjacency treegrid. It usually takes quite a long time to load (with chrome it can be 1min, with IE it takes even longer).

```
        grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        editurl: 'ajax/modify',
        mtype: 'POST',
        loadonce: true,
        datastr: jobs,
        height: 600,
        autowidth: true,
        forceFit: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: true,
        sortable: false,
        toppager: true,
        treeGrid: true,
        treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
        treedatatype: 'POST',
        ExpandColumn: 'import',
        ExpandColClick: true,
        loadComplete: function() {
            grid.setColProp('City', {
                editoptions: {
                    value: function(){
                        var options = select_options('City');
                        options[""] = '';
                        return options;
                    }
                }
            });}
```

As far as I know paging doesn't work with adjacency treegrid. i have already set it up though, any ideas how i can improve the performance? Why is it so slow in IE?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid and jQuery you use? How many items of TreeGrid you load at once? Which version of IE you used in your tests? You don't included `colModel`. How many columns you have?

Comment: jquery 1.9.2. and jqGrid 4.6.0. I am using IE 9 right now. I have 25 columns. I am loading around 4500 rows.

Comment: How many children have one node? How many root items exist? I recommend you to try the test with the latest version of free jqGrid. You need just use `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` and `https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. How many time is loading with it?

Comment: level 0 has up to 4 children. level 1 has up to 20 children. level 2 is a leaf node.
I am only loading it once to display it all.
ok i will take a look at that.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have updated the jqgrid versions now. I had added a new button using navButtonAdd, but now it has disappeared?

Comment: Sorry, but where is the code? Where is the test data? **One have to be able to reproduce the problem** to solve it. So you should provide enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is still just as slow. Sorry, I'm still new to this. How can I provide test data?

Comment: What is "slow". Is it 5 sec or 500 sec? Do you measure the loading time in jqGrid 4.6.0 and in the current state of free jqGrid on github? Is there are some time difference? I don't know which possibilities you have and in which form you have the data. You can for example create JSFiddle demo. You can send me the demo via email oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com. I can look at the demo. If you want to make the working of the TreeGrid really quickly with 4500 rows then you should load the data of demand instead of loading all at once. It will dramatically improve the performance.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Do you have an example of how I can load data on demand with a jqGrid adjacency tree grid? I would like to use paging but I don't think this is possible for tree grids?

Comment: Loading on demand and paging are two different things. Paging of TreeGrid is not possible at all. For loading on demand the server should return only top level (or two levels for example). When the click on some node of the grid to open it jqGrid will send **additional request** to the server with additional parameters `nodeid`, `n_level`, `parentid`. Thus the server should examine the parameters and to return only the corresponding children.  See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:adjacency_model#what_we_post).